# No enum const class in Enum

Tags: java, enums

```
public enum ProcessorFactory {
    A("ap") {
        Processor create() throws Exception {
            return new AProcessor();
        }
    },

    B("bp"){
        Processor create() throws Exception {
            return new BProcessor();
        }
    };

    abstract Processor create() throws Exception;

    public static Processor getProcessor(String product) throws Exception {
        ProcessorFactory factory = valueOf(product);
        return factory.create();
    }

    private String product;

    private ProcessorFactory(String product) {
        this.product = product;
    }
 }
```

Now when I try to call

```
ProcessorFactory.getProcessor("ap");
```

It throws above exception. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `ProcessorFactory.getProcessor("A")`

or add a new method:

```
public ProcessorFactory getbyProduct(String product) {
   for (ProcessorFactory factory : values()) {
      if (factory.getProduct().equals(processor)) {
         return factory;
      }
   }
   return null; // or throw an exception
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, there really is no enum value named "ap". You only have `A` and `B`. `valueOf` does not use what you store in `product`. If you want to get enums by some custom identifier, you'll have to use some translation map that will convert `product` to `ProcessorFactory` value (or just go over all values, which is less efficient).

Comment: Translation map is not always faster. My microbenchmarks show that on small enums (like most) and String keys it is faster to iterate because of the higher costs of String's `hashCode()`. For numeric keys the map is usually faster.

Comment: If getProcessor method is being called within a loop (every 15 sec) continuously, which would be more efficient. Map or iterating over values? Considering Size of enum is 5.

Comment: @Jitendra, I don't think this matters that match. For a small set of values, use whatever's easier for you. I'm saying this because enums usually have very few values - on cases where the number of value depends on some input, use maps as they are much more efficient than those O(n) loops.

Comment: I agree with eran. I did not get significant differences in my benchmarks even after calling it several million times. My advice: Keep it simple and iterate.

Comment: +1, eran didn't specify *how* to implement the map, one would be to iterate another would be to use a standard implementation subclassing `Map`...

Comment: thnx.. went with the iterative approach as in first answer.